# CakePHP Routes and Google Webmaster Tools verification

Tags: url, cakephp, seo, google-search-console

I am working on cakephp project I have URL like :

```
 http://www.example.com/
```

As CakePHP takes an url like

```
http://www.exaple.com/controll/function_name
```

I was going through the [web-master tools site verification](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35179&topic=2370564&ctx=topic) where I was verifying my site,
Google provides verification file(HTML) which I need to store in root directory.

The problem is that CakePHP does not allow to put .HTML in the URL, so how can verify my site then ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They also offer a [meta tag that you can use for verification](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35659). Use that instead.

Answer (score 5):

There is another option that isn't mentioned yet to my surprise, but you can put files you would like to serve "as is" under the `app/webroot` folder. So if you create `app/webroot/google-site-verification-a12bc345.html`, you (and more importantly, Google) can access that page through

```
http://cakeapp.com/google-site-verification-a12bc345.html
```

Comment: I think the reason why html file method as not been mentioned so far is because OP had mentioned that *CakePHP does not allow to put .HTML in the URL*. But that's a good point and should be mentioned for broader audience (+1)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what John said, Google Webmaster tools can be verified via [Google Analytics's](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=185871) if you use one.

However for Google Analytic's verification, Google Analytics JavaScript tracking code must be in the `<head>` (not the `<body>`) section of your page. Sometimes GA code exist in other JS files or at the bottom of the page, which is problematic.

If you do not have Google Analytic's implemented (and you are not planning to) the simplest solution is what [John has said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14402182/1916110) - using meta tag verification.